# Simple Python Package Structure Not Working

Tags: python, import, virtualenv, package, importerror

My enviornment is virtualenv with python2.7

I have created an extremly simple python package to try and indentify the problem. I have package that contains sub-packages all with an `__init__.py` file, but after building I cannot import a file from the sub-package. All the files are empty except the file I'm trying to import, which contains only a dummy class.

`class LazyUrl(object): pass`.

#### Package Structure

```
- setup.py
- sloth_toolkit/
        - __init__.py
        - webtools/
                - __init__.py
                - urls.py
        - systools/
                - __init__.py
        - utils/
                - __init__.py
```

#### setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name = 'sloth-toolkit',
    packages = ['sloth_toolkit'],
    version = '0.0.01',
    author = 'crispycret',

    description='Contains lazy rich objects, such as the LazyUrl..',
)
```

#### urls.py

```
class LazyUrl(object):
    pass
```

I then install the package, move the terminal to the user root directory to avoid importing the source, and run `ipython`. I import the package with no problems, then I try to import/access the dummy class `LazyUrl`, this is where it breaks.

#### ipython session

```
In [1]: import sloth_toolkit

In [2]: sloth_toolkit.webtools.urls.LazyUrl()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-edc6d4b8bbf3> in <module>()
----> 1 sloth_toolkit.webtools.urls.LazyUrl()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'webtools'

In [3]: from sloth_toolkit.webtools import urls
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-f6b31fa7f72c> in <module>()
----> 1 from sloth_toolkit.webtools import urls

ImportError: No module named webtools
```

This is driving me insane. I believe the problem is my enviornment put I don't know.

Heres the project I was working on `https://github.com/crispycret/sloth-toolkit`.

After installing in a virtualenv and importing the package I get this error from importing the `LazyUrl` class to the packages main `__init__.py` file.

#### Real Package Error

```
In [1]: import sloth_toolkit
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-70e153ca48f0> in <module>()
----> 1 import sloth_toolkit

/home/crispycret/Documents/sloth-testing/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sloth_toolkit-0.0.11-py2.7.egg/sloth_toolkit/__init__.py in <module>()
      3 # from . import utilities
      4 
----> 5 from .webtools.urls import LazyUrl
      6 from .systools.paths import LazyPath
      7 

ImportError: No module named webtools.urls
```

Comment: If you look at the directory where the package was installed, does it match that package layout?  It's possible some `setup.py` mistake is causing it to not install properly.

Comment: I think so. I've updated the question, including the `setup.py` file

Answer (score 1):

## Quick Summary

**Problem:** the `__init__.py` files shouldn't be empty.

**Solution:** have the `__init__.py` files import all functions, classes, even *submodules* (!) that you want your package to include.

#### `sloth_toolkit/__init__.py`

```py
from .webtools import *
from .systools import *
from .utils import *
```

#### `sloth_toolkit/webtools/__init__.py`

```py
from .urls import *  # OR from .urls import LazyUrl
```

I hope this helps! I've added this answer because this is a common question for python beginners. **This is still how it works in Python 3.X**.